# Combine files in one

Tags: linux, unix, gzip, solaris, sunos

Currently I am in this directory-

```
/data/real/test
```

When I do `ls -lt` at the command prompt. I get like below something-

```
REALTIME_235000.dat.gz
REALTIME_234800.dat.gz
REALTIME_234600.dat.gz
REALTIME_234400.dat.gz
REALTIME_234200.dat.gz
```

How can I consolidate the above five `dat.gz files` into one `dat.gz file` in Unix without any data loss. I am new to Unix and I am not sure on this. Can anyone help me on this?

**Update:-**

I am not sure which is the best way whether I should unzip each of the five file then combine into one? Or 
combine all those `five dat.gz` into one `dat.gz`?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If it's OK to concatenate files content in random order, then following command will do the trick:

```
zcat REALTIME*.dat.gz | gzip > out.dat.gz
```

**Update**

This should solve order problem:

```
zcat $(ls -t REALTIME*.dat.gz) | gzip > out.dat.gz
```

Comment: `zcat *.gz | gzip > out.dat.gz` I tried doing like this. And I got this error `REALTIME_EXPORT_v1x0_20120801_9_T_234000_234200.dat.gz.Z: No such file or directory
` for all the five files. Why is it so?

Comment: @Nevzz03 I can't reproduce this problem. I'm using **bash** on linux and same file names.

Comment: @Nevzz03 Are you on Solaris instead of Linux? If so, use `gzcat *.gz | gzip > out.dat.gz` instead. The `zcat` utility on Solaris works with a different compression suite (`compress` and `decompress`) that uses `.Z` as a suffix instead of `.gz`. This might also be the case on other non-Linux Unixen (AIX, etc.)...

Comment: If you see my above comment, There is extra `Z` that gets appended after the file name. `dat.gz.Z` Why is it so?

Comment: Please see answer by Mark Adler. ~1000 times faster and more correct.

Comment: @Morlock Mark is using `cat`, so it'll not work with compressed files that OP is asking for.

Comment: @IvanNevostruev Yes it will, that is the beauty of the gzip format. If you cat a.txt and b.txt THEN gzip or gzip them both then cat, you get two archives with the exact same content. To verify, unzip the two archives and use md5sum. (I just re-tried it to confirm). That is why Mark Adler pointed to the fact that it is unnecessary to decompress then recompress them.

Answer (score 5):

What do you want to happen when you gunzip the result?  If you want the five files to reappear, then you need to use something other than the gzip (.gz) format.  You would need to either use tar (.tar.gz) or zip (.zip).

If you want the result of the gunzip to be the concatenation of the gunzip of the original files, then you can simply cat (not zcat or gzcat) the files together.  gunzip will then decompress them to a single file.

```
cat [files in whatever order you like] > combined.gz
```

Then:

```
gunzip combined.gz
```

will produce an output that is the concatenation of the gunzip of the original files.

The suggestion to decompress them all and then recompress them as one stream is completely unnecessary.

Answer (score -1):

It seems almost like a black magic, but you can actually **concatenate GZ files directly**!

The format was made for this (along with MP3). Internally, GZ is organized in independent chunks of compressed stream, each with its own header, compression dictionary, checksum, and so on.

So when you concatenate several GZ files, the uncompressed stream is exactly the concatenation of original files.